# How do I fix my zsh prompt now that I've upgraded to snow leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, zsh, zshrc

I recently upgraded my system to snow leopard and now my prompt doesn't work properly.  I have this line in my .zshrc file:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_no_bold[cyan]%}%n@%{$fg_no_bold[red]%}%m%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}$(git_branch)%{$reset_color%}: '
```

(where "git_branch" is a function that give me information about the current git branch I'm working on).  The problem is that the colors and "git_branch" function aren't being evaluated, they are taken literally, so my prompt is:

```
%{$fg_no_bold[cyan]%}username@%{$fg_no_bold[red]%}machinename%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}$(git_branch)%{$reset_color%}:
```

The colors are nice, but the part I'd really like to get working is the git branch info.  I've been googling, but haven't found anything yet.  I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to zsh, so links to helpful resources would also be appreciated.

```
zsh --version
zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)
```

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Have you tried double quotes?

Comment: Yeah, double quotes didn't fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at a bunch of config files I discovered that adding these lines:

```
setopt prompt_subst
autoload colors

colors
```

caused my prompt to correctly interpret my color codes again.